# How to capture key events while there are candidates in input method?

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture key inputs before they are committed to an EditText. When there's no candidate, KeyListener is just enough. When it comes to candidates, KeyListener never get actions while typing, instead, after choose and commit, KeyListener gets an "ACTION_MULTIPLE" and keycode shows 0(Unknown).

Is there any possibility that I can capture the keys typed?

Update:

I didn't mean TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged. I mean I'm typing keys, and still not choosing something from the candidates. I want the first candidate, or keys I typed, but not the result I choose to commit to the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextWatcher API to capture the events http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html... hope it helps

Comment: It wont work as what I touch is the input method but not my view, i think.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want... Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. Updated now.